# How to display a list of children objects on detail view for Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models: `Setting` and `SettingsGroup`.

When someone clicks on a specific `SettingsGroup` in the Django Admin and the edit/detail page appears I'd like for the child `Setting` objects to be displayed but as a list not a form.

I know that Django has [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/) but this displays the children as editable forms.

My concern isn't with the child objects being editable from the parent object but rather the amount of space it consumes. I'd rather have a list with either a link to the appropriate child record or that changes a particular object to be inline editable.

Here is my `Setting` model:

```py
class Setting(models.Model):
  key = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
  value = models.TextField(blank=True)
  group = models.ForeignKey('SettingsGroup', blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.key)
```

And the `SettingsGroup` model:

```py
class SettingsGroup(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

The method I don't want to use (or need to find a different way to use) is `InlineModelAdmin` which appears in my `admin.py` currently as:

```py
class SettingsGroupInline(admin.StackedInlin):
  model = Setting
  fk_name = 'group'

@admin.register(SettingsGroup)
class SettingsGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ SettingGroupsInline, ]
```

Here is an example of how I'd like it to work:

- There is a `MySettings` object, an instance of the `SettingsGroup` model.
- There is a `CoolSetting` object and a `BoringSetting` object, each an instance of the `Setting` model.
- The `CoolSetting` object has its `group` set to the `MySettings` object.
- The `BoringSetting` object does not have a `group` set.
- When I open the detail/edit view of the Django Admin for the `MySettings` object I see the normal edit form for the `MySettings` object and below it the `CoolSetting` object (but not as a form).
- I do not see the `BoringSetting` object because it is not a child/member/related of/to `MySettings`.

I have some ideas on how this could be accomplished but this seems like fairly basic functionality and I don't want to go building something if Django (or other existing code) provides a way to accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just access the children using something like `Setting.objects.filter(group=SettingsGroup.objects.get(name={name}))`

If being presented in a template you could pass the SettingsGroup name to the context and iterate over the children and present them however you like.

I may not understand your question exactly so if this is not what you're looking for let me know!

Comment: Something like this should work, I'm just wondering if there is a more declarative way.